# Button action called without pressing it

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I had a render function with a button that redirects to another page.
When I enter the page, it does immediately trigger to the page (without cliking the button) and display the following warning message : cannot update during an existing state transition

```
render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text > {this.state.text} </Text>
        <Button onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
                title = "Go Home" />
      </View>
    );
 }
```

I solved it with the following code, but I don't understand why the previous did'nt work.

```
render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text > {this.state.text} </Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
                title = "Go Home" />
      </View>
    );
 }
```

Could you explain me why the behavior is different ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
```

You are calling the navigate function and passing it's output to the onPress.

When you do:

```
() => {
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
}
```

you are passing an arrow function (not a call) and this function contains a call to your navigate, but the arrow function isn't called until the button is pressed.

Your solution with the use of an arrow function is the right thing to do, because you have to pass a parameter, if you didn't have to pass it you could do:

```
<Button onPress={this.someOfMyFunctions.bind(this)}
                title = "Go Home" />
```

This would result in the someOfMyFunction call when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you are actually calling the function in the first case.

In your second code block you are passing the function to the `onClick` handler which is what you want to do. The value should be a function, not a call to a function.

Hope that helps.